# Join all multiple columns to the same column of another table

Tags: sqlite, join, lookup

Let's say I have two tables:

Table "Combinations"

```
first  second  result
1      1       0
1      2       1
1      3       0
2      3       2
```

Table "Names"

```
ID  Name
1   Item1
2   Item2
3   Item3
```

How do I join these together to an output like this? Basically just for "looking up" the IDs?

```
firstItem  secondItem  resultingItem
Item1      Item1       -
Item1      Item2       Item1
Item1      Item3       -
Item2      Item3       Item2
```

Comment: Try this: SELECT (SELECT Name WHERE ID = first) AS firstItem, (SELECT Name WHERE ID = second) AS secondItem, (SELECT Name WHERE ID = result) AS resultingItem FROM Combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trhee columns in "Combinations" table hold the ID value of the "Names" table, so basically you have three foreing keys to the same filed of tha same table.

In order to also list the combinations where there there is no result we need to use left or right join so as to preserve the Combinations records that don't have a match for the result colum. In the case of the query below I use left join because the Combinations table is on the left of the condition.

This can be accomplished like this:

```
select n1.Name, n2.Name, nr.Name
from
Combinations c left join Names n1 on c.first = n1.ID
left join Names n2 on c.second = n2.ID
left join Names nr on c.result = nr.ID;
```